# How Would One Go About Learning To Program Operating Systems in Java?

Tags: java, c, assembly, binary, operating-system

How would you go about learning to program Operating Systems in Java (And Assembly I am guessing)?. Any good resources would be great, but I was mainly looking for an answer that was Java specific (atleast mostly Java). I am reading http://wiki.osdev.org/, but that is mainly talking about C. Thanks!

P.S: If Java wouldn't be good suited for OS development, please tell me.

**EDIT:** Also please note that I do not plan to develop a big, amazing OS. I just want to be put on the right track, and make something that works.

Comment: This is completely off-topic. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: Programming an OS in Java would be similar to building a real house out of Lego® blocks.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Are you calling Java a toy? :)

Comment: Please show us the code you have already written for this, and the problems you are having, "writing an OS in Java is hard" is not a problem that can be solved here on SO.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Are you calling Lego® a toy? ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: As Yannik already said, C is the more suitable language for that, because you have a more direct access to the machine. Java is a High-level programming language, which suggests, that you need 'lower levels' (in other languages) which will make the communication between the JVM and the machine code possible. theoretically speaking you could create some sort of an OS with Java, since Java is as 'powerfull' as C (in theory). Meaning there is nothing you can't do in Java, but you would have to find a new JVM that communicates with your hardware directly.

Comment: There have been operating systems (mostly of the "toy" variety) written in a derivative of Java, but in general it's not done, for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm, dude i think programming operation systems in java or operating kernels in java woulde be a very bad idea.

Here a some reasons:

- You have not really access to the hardware
- You would need to have an installed JRE
- Java is partially interpreted, and partially compiled. The "slowness" wouldnt be adequate
- and many more reasons.

So, it has a good reason, that the author of the website mainly talks about C, its because it gets you acces to the hardware, and so on. Check the wikipedia article for more reasons.

Greetz

Comment: Thanks! What you said about Java is correct, I guess I didn't really think it through...

Comment: Beyond not being a good idea, I am pretty sure that it is not even possible.